# Как загружать ресурсы из сети в папку приложения?

Tags: сеть, android, java

Требуется загружать ресурсы, допустим, с веб-ресурса, после чего сохранять их в устройство, допустим, в SDCARD/Application/ и в дальнейшем использовать по нуждам приложения. По поддержке сети в андроиде мало чего видел. Вопрос: как реализовать эту самую загрузку картинок, звуков и прочего в устройство с сохранением в папку?

Вот что пока нашел: [how to download file/image from url to your device](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device).

Comment: Какой язык вы используете? Java или C++?

Comment: Android SDK - Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
URL u  = new URL("http://...");
URLConnection c = url.openConnection();

c.connect();

InputStream is = url.openStream();
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("...");

byte data[] = new byte[c.getContentLength()];

is.close();
os.close();
```

Плюс добавить поддержку исключений и грузить не целиком, а частями.

Comment: Ну, в принципе это почти аналогично тому, что я нашел. Вынести в функцию, сделать анимацию загрузки, и по завершению использовать ресы. Грузить частями, стоит ли грузить частями файлы не более 100кб?